# Hey guyz i have been searching solution all over but didn't find any thing similar:

Tags: xslt

I have following structured source xml document:

```
<a>
    <k>
       <l> l_hello </l>
    </k>        
    <b id="0">
      <c>
        <d>d_hello</d>
      </c>
    </b>
    <e id="0">
     <f>
      <g>
        <h>h_hello</h>
      </g>
     </f>
   </e>
 </a>
```

Now what i want to do is ...... i want to repeat whole `<b>` tag 5 times and parallel to it `<e>` tag 5 times with all the attributes in place . I mean to say i want following out to get generated:

```
 <a>
    <k>
       <l> l_hello </l>
    </k>        
    <b id="0">
      <c>
        <d>d_hello</d>
      </c>
    </b>
    <e id="0">
     <f>
      <g>
        <h>h_hello</h>
      </g>
     </f>
   </e>
     <b id="0">
      <c>
        <d>d_hello</d>
      </c>
    </b>
    <e id="0">
     <f>
      <g>
        <h>h_hello</h>
      </g>
     </f>
   </e>
     <b id="0">
      <c>
        <d>d_hello</d>
      </c>
    </b>
    <e id="0">
     <f>
      <g>
        <h>h_hello</h>
      </g>
     </f>
   </e>
     <b id="0">
      <c>
        <d>d_hello</d>
      </c>
    </b>
    <e id="0">
     <f>
      <g>
        <h>h_hello</h>
      </g>
     </f>
   </e>
     <b id="0">
      <c>
        <d>d_hello</d>
      </c>
    </b>
    <e id="0">
     <f>
      <g>
        <h>h_hello</h>
      </g>
     </f>
   </e>
 </a>
```

Anyone if come up with a solution would be of great help....I have generated code but that's all wrong so no point in pasting it here.....

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0. And change your title to something more descriptive and appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very simple way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="k"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="e"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="e"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="e"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="e"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="b"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="e"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> tell me some way where all tags other than b and e should come once
>   and b and e should be repeated 5 times

That too can be simple:

```
<xsl:template match="/a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::b or self::e)]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="be" select="b|e" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="$be"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$be"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$be"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$be"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$be"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks michael for such a quick reply, but i want to implement it with the help of a loop , and yes its xslt 1.0

Comment: the structure i have uploaded of the input xml is just an example , my xml is almost 35000 tags long , anywaz tell me some way where all tags other than b and e should come once and b and e should be repeated 5 times with the help of a loop

Comment: Hey michael thanks again for the quick help and its working ......... i am new to xslt so might be asking for your help whenever needed.............